# GLTF to OBJ Textures/MTL not exporting correctly

Tags: materials

I have several models in GLTF format and want to export them to OBJ, of course with textures / MTL file.
I import the GLTF files using "KSon's GLTF Importer" addon. In Blender, they get displayed correctly, with the textures. When I export them to OBJ, an MTL file gets written, but in the MTL file there are no paths to texture files, just some materials defined. "Write Materials" is checked in OBJ-export settings.

Any ideas? Any help ist appreciated. 
Note: I am very new to Blender

Comment: Might be worth trying the official gltf importer in Blender 2.8.

Comment: Tried it, got the same result. Correctly displayed in Blender, exported to obj, mtl gets written but no textures in it.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Just to avoid misundestanding the mtl itself doesn't contain any textures, it will just reference them. If you open the file in an editor you should see entries named map_Kd followed by the file name. In order to open/import the obj with textures in another software the .obj, .mtl and all texture need to be in the same directory.

Comment: yes, i know that. the mtl file looks like following:

`# Blender MTL File: 'untitled.blend'
# Material Count: 2

newmtl 07___Default
Ns 323.999994
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.0 0.0 0.0
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2

newmtl lambert2
Ns 323.999994
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.800000 0.800000 0.800000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.0 0.0 0.0
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2)`

Comment: sorry, dont know how to properly format as "code".
There is no "map" paramter. The model contains at least one texture (jpg)

Comment: Is the texture packed into the gltf or is it an extra file? If it's the former you'll have to save the texture to disk first and assign that one in the material before exporting to obj.